# Ransack sort on .count result of an has_many relation, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, count, ransack

I want to sort a table (with a sort_link I suppose) or filter the result of a .count method.
I have a model where a `Candidate` has_many `Assets`

I built a table that lists all my candidates where a column show the result of `candidate.assets.count` so I know how many assets a candidate have.

I want to add a filter (I could be a value from 0 to 2 for example) or a sort link generated by ransack to sort the column ascending or descending.

I hope I was clear about my issue. I checked the doc of ransack and ransacker but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Thanks you for helping me. cheers.

Comment: The best solution would be to filter if candidates has no assets or the oposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out using a counter cache field and sort the field with ransack